# Design critique

Tags: adobe-indesign, critique

Im a digital marketing apprentice and one of my jobs is to design leaflets and promotional content. So I have been trying to work on my graphic design in my free time, i would love some feedback on this leaflet. I have no academic background in design but i do have a background in art.

Please be as bruteally honest as possable if that comes with how i could improve :)

Thanks[image]

Design #2

[image]

Comment: Open critique questions are too broad, it's better if you focus on some specific aspect. Check the [guidelines for critique questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work)

Comment: It's puny. It doesn't make clear that you (who in the hell, cannot be sure) are going strong and will show it in the mentioned races - do not miss it!  The top  of the ad should be aggressive. Now its nothing.  BTW. Is the Clio Sport logo just like your target people have used to see it?

Comment: @user287001 the logo is the same to what they usually see.Ive updated the design to try be more aggressive.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. The grammar is really poor. Maybe have someone proof read it  - "our sponsored race car is racing in this weekend" -  is extremely awkward - maybe try "our sponsored car is racing this weekend" instead , and "We additionally we be racing" is not grammatical. Try "Additionally, we will be racing".

Comment: Also I think the body text is mostly redundant. Why not just go for something that;s more punchy and less wordy [like this perhaps](https://imgur.com/redpt3S)

Comment: @BillyKerr
Thanks for all the advice and i will be sure to learn from this in future posters. I was told about this last minute so i had to submit the second version. but i have learn alot from reading these comments thanks :)

Comment: "We additionally we be racing" -- is exceptionally poor. And "Lights out and away we go" -- so it's racing in the dark?

Answer (score 1):

Please understand, you are posting at a *design* site, asking other *designers* to critique your *design*. Any comments are meant to be **helpful** and not any sort of "personal attack".

---

Copy doesn't *actually* make sense....

- "We additionally we be racing..."
- "Lights out and away we go" So it's racing in the dark??

The map pins are superfluous, distracting, and unnecessary.

Why is "Silverstone" all uppercase and underlined in the top image? If it's not a link, don't underline anything. Use boldface or italic.

All uppercase type is generally more difficult to read for people, especially in the middle of other copy. Avoid all uppercase when you can.

Who is "We"? Is it Powerlight/Fitgerald? It doesn't appear to be. Those just look like tacked on logos after the fact. This looks more like an announcement for Cliosport. Is that the "we"?

The typeface used for the copy in the top image is too thin and has too low contrast.

The way the Cliosport logo and "championship" are two different line lengths bothers me. It's just inherently unbalanced.

Is that *actually* the Cliosport logo? I can't find *anything* similar -- https://cliosport.net/ (It may be a legitimate logo that the internet doesn't seem to know about)

Dirty, rough, mock up....

[image]

I would also change the typeface for the race events.. but I didn't feel like typing those out....

Comment: You speak for me also. The grammar is appalling. Like a non-native English speaker wrote the copy.  Also I think the body text is mostly superfluous.  I think "Lights out" might be for the starting lights, like in F1 when all the red lights go out when the race starts.  But "Lights out" also has some negative connotations in English. I'd avoid this phrase.

Comment: @BillyKerr I considered that for the "lights out" but **that car** is not a drag racer or F1. So Lights out wouldn't seem to be applicable. "Clio" seems to be the brand of the car... like "MiniCooper racing" of a sort. https://cliosport.net/

Comment: Yes. Clio is a Renault model, popular in Europe and here in the UK.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your design options may have their own benefits. In 1st, text size is big so more legible. In the 2nd it's small. You need to think which is more important to you.

But still, each of them needs many improvements that may help them make better e.g.

**1st option**:

Some text is going too close to hexagons.

*WE ARE LIVE* could be a bit more bold like the italic text in your 2nd option to put more emphasis.

You can try to move the car wallpaper (not the clipping hexagons) a little towards bottom right so it has some more empty space over it. It might look better.

**2nd option**:

You may want to move that slanted shape little bit to right side so it gives little more breathing to the text on left side of it.

*Made in Britain* placement doesn't look quite okay.

In my opinion, the location icon is little too big as compared to address text. Or the whole address element needs to go down a little bit so the icon doesn't mix with the date above it.

---

These are my personal opinions about these design options, based on what I observed. You may want to follow suggestions from other answer(s) too.

Note that sometimes this kind of designs which have more text and more than one logos and images needs many more options. Maybe 4 or 5. That gives you a better idea which could work better.

Answer (score 0):

Its a good start, but not spectacular

- Boring fonts. Try something more exciting, its for racing.
- Text too thin. Use bold and extra bold.
- Too much leading on text.
- Sponsor logos too close together.
- Center align everything on the page and put the car in the middle, not in the corner.
- Spice it up. It looks like a law & tax seminar flyer. Try some texture in the background and consider a non-white background. With these things, the more decoration you add, the more sense it makes. Google images search racing flyer and you'll see what I mean.